# Game of guesses

Tags: python

```
import random
print("lets play the game")
print("you will be given 3 chances to play the game")
i=1
score=0

while(i<=3):
    c=random.randint(1,10)
    
    d=int(input("enter your choice: "))
    if(d==c):
        score+=1
        print("congrats it was the correct guess")
        print(f"you have {3-i} chances left +1")
    elif(d>c):
        print(" oops !!your choice was too high")
        print(f"you have {3-i} chances left,better luck next time")
    elif(d<c):
         print(" oops !!your choice was too low")
         print(f"you have {3-i} chances left,better luck next time")
    i+=1

print(f"your score is {score}")
```

When i run the code ,I get the result wrong sometimes.
Eg: If the number is 7 then the result is too high
and when i press number 5 the result is too low. So,the only possible answer is 6.
But the result shows the number is too low or high again.

Comment: Once you guess and it is too high or low, it goes back to the top of the loop and generates a new random number,

Comment: `while(i<=3):
    c=random.randint(1,10)` the problem lies here, do you know why?

Comment: You should consider generating the number before the game loop.
Here you change the number to guess at each round.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the c variable over the while, because after doing your first guess you are changing the c variable to another random number.

```
import random
print("lets play the game")
print("you will be given 3 chances to play the game")
i=1
score=0
c=random.randint(1,10)

while(i<=3):
    
    d=int(input("enter your choice: "))
    if(d==c):
        score+=1
        print("congrats it was the correct guess")
        print(f"you have {3-i} chances left +1")
    elif(d>c):
        print(" oops !!your choice was too high")
        print(f"you have {3-i} chances left,better luck next time")
    elif(d<c):
         print(" oops !!your choice was too low")
         print(f"you have {3-i} chances left,better luck next time")
    i+=1

print(f"your score is {score}")
```